# css3 3D transform

Tags: css, transform

I have a triangle and I need it to rotate 360 deg around the bottom left triangle angle. I need this point to be fixed and just the triangle rotate around it.

here's my code

```css
figure {
  background-color:#000;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 20px 1%;
 height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}


.icons {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:20%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 background: url("http://imgh.us/triangle_6.svg") no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.45s;
 transition: transform 0.45s;
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 transform-origin: bottom left;
}

 figure:hover .icons{
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
}
```

```html
<figure>
<div class="icons">
</div>
</figure>
```

I need it to rotate 360 deg from static origin and want it to be the bottom left angle of the triangle .
is this possible ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you set .icons container's width and height as 50% which made the .icons container not square but rectangle. The SVG triangle is inscribed in square, so if you put the triangle into rectangle and centered it, there was some space between left bottom .icons corner and left bottom triangle's corner. you should specify the width and height of .icons to be the same (to make it the square) or play with width and height of background triangle.svg (don't use %)

```css
figure {
  background-color:#000;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 20px 1%;
 height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}


.icons {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:20%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 background: url("http://imgh.us/triangle_6.svg") no-repeat left bottom;
 background-size: auto auto;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.45s;
 transition: transform 0.45s;
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 transform-origin: bottom left;
}

 figure:hover .icons{
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
}
```

```html
<figure>
<div class="icons">
</div>
</figure>
```

Comment: You've got 3 options, you can set figure to have the same width and height (to make it square), you can set .icons to be the square or you can change the background-size from '100% 100%' to 'auto auto' and change brackground-position to 'left bottom'. You can right click on your triangle and select on the bottom of the list 'Inspect element' and check the highlight of the container .icons is wider than the svg triangle. that's the problem. transform-origin is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can lock in the point of transformation by using the `transform-origin` property. In this case I have set the value to `bottom left`.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.rotate {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: green;
 position: absolute;
    right:0;
    transition: all 1s linear;
   -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  
}

.box:hover .rotate {
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="rotate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already use transform-origin: bottom left  , however this also not rotate around static angle . I need to make the angle static and only the shape rotate around it.

Comment: @YahyaEssam apologies have fixed the code. You must set `transform-origin` on the element before it is rotated